# Why is Prettier extension not working in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier extension is not working on my VS Code since I installed it for the first time. I have autosave enabled. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, autosave doesn't trigger "Format on Save". Try saving manually (e.g. Ctrl + S) and see if that formats the code.